# How to find the largest value of a hash in an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

In my array, I'm trying to retrieve the key with the largest value of "value_2", so in this case, "B":

```
myArray = [
  "A" => {
    "value_1" => 30,
    "value_2" => 240
  },
  "B" => {
    "value_1" => 40,
    "value_2" => 250
  },
  "C" => {
    "value_1" => 18,
    "value_2" => 60
  }
]

myArray.each do |array_hash|
 array_hash.each do |key, value|
  if value["value_2"] == array_hash.values.max
   puts key
  end
 end
end
```

I get the error:

```
"comparison of Hash with Hash failed (ArgumentError)".
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you aware that `myArray` contains a single element which is another array. And that inner array in turn contains a single hash with three keys and other hashes as values. Is that really the structure you want?

Comment: As @Stefan mentioned, maybe you should review your structure: `myArray.size #=> 1`. It just contains an Hash: `myArray.first #=> {"A"=>{"value_1"=>30, "value_2"=>240}, "B"=>{"value_1"=>40, "value_2"=>250}, "C"=>{"value_1"=>18, "value_2"=>60}}`

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: The structure of `myArray` is suspicious. An array of hashes where each hash key is different should have been a compound hash/hash of hashes. Your question really should be about how to gather the data and create the variable. "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)" explains. Once the data is in the right form it's easy to do more with it.

Answer (score 1):

Though equivalent, the array given in the question is generally written:

```
arr = [{ "A" => { "value_1" => 30, "value_2" => 240 } },
       { "B" => { "value_1" => 40, "value_2" => 250 } },
       { "C" => { "value_1" => 18, "value_2" =>  60 } }]
```

We can find the desired key as follows:

```
arr.max_by { |h| h.values.first["value_2"] }.keys.first
  #=> "B"
```

See [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by). The steps are:

```
g = arr.max_by { |h| h.values.first["value_2"] }
  #=> {"B"=>{"value_1"=>40, "value_2"=>250}} 
a = g.keys
  #=> ["B"] 
a.first
  #=> "B"
```

In calculating `g`, for

```
h = arr[0]
  #=> {"A"=>{"value_1"=>30, "value_2"=>240}}
```

the block calculation is

```
a = h.values
  #=> [{"value_1"=>30, "value_2"=>240}] 
b = a.first
  #=> {"value_1"=>30, "value_2"=>240} 
b["value_2"]   
  #=> 240
```

---

Suppose now `arr` is as follows:

```
arr << { "D" => { "value_1" => 23, "value_2" => 250 } }
  #=> [{"A"=>{"value_1"=>30, "value_2"=>240}},
  #    {"B"=>{"value_1"=>40, "value_2"=>250}},
  #    {"C"=>{"value_1"=>18, "value_2"=>60}},
  #    {"D"=>{"value_1"=>23, "value_2"=>250}}]
```

and we wish to return an array of all keys for which the value of `"value_2"` is maximum (`["B", "D"]`). We can obtain that as follows.

```
max_val = arr.map { |h| h.values.first["value_2"] }.max
  #=> 250
arr.select { |h| h.values.first["value_2"] == max_val }.flat_map(&:keys)
  #=> ["B", "D"]
```

`flat_map(&:keys)` is shorthand for:

```
flat_map { |h| h.keys }
```

which returns the same array as:

```
map { |h| h.keys.first }
```

See [Enumerable#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map).

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
p myArray.pop.max_by{|k,v|v["value_2"]}.first
```

Output

```
"B"
```

Comment: Why `pop` here? That damages the array.

Comment: Please use proper whitespace between your braces, operators, etc. Readability is very important when coding, for your future self and those who might inherit the code. The style guides for languages discuss this, including Ruby's, for instance "[Spaces and Operators](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#spaces-and-operators)". "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live. Code for readability." — John Woods

Answer (score 0):

I guess the idea of your solution is looping through each hash element and compare the found minimum value with `hash["value_2"]`.

But you are getting an error at

```
if value["value_2"] == array_hash.values.max
```

Because the `array_hash.values` is still a hash

```
{"A"=>{"value_1"=>30, "value_2"=>240}}.values.max 
#=> {"value_1"=>30, "value_2"=>240}
```

It should be like this:

```
max = nil
max_key = ""
myArray.each do |array_hash|
  array_hash.each do |key, value|
    if max.nil? || value.values.max > max
      max = value.values.max
      max_key = key
    end
  end
end

# max_key #=> "B"
```

Another solution:

```
myArray.map{ |h| h.transform_values{ |v| v["value_2"] } }.max_by{ |k| k.values }.keys.first
```

Comment: "Magical" low numbers like that are often a problem. It's best to use `nil` to indicate "no max" or instead pick a value at random from the list so you know that it *could* be the max.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
my_array = [
  "A" => {
    "value_1" => 30,
    "value_2" => 240
  },
  "B" => {
    "value_1" => 40,
    "value_2" => 250
  },
  "C" => {
    "value_1" => 18,
    "value_2" => 60
  }
]

h = Hash[*my_array] 
# => {"A"=>{"value_1"=>30, "value_2"=>240},
#     "B"=>{"value_1"=>40, "value_2"=>250},
#     "C"=>{"value_1"=>18, "value_2"=>60}}

k = h.max_by { |k, v| v['value_2'] }.first # => "B"
```

`Hash[*my_array]` takes the array of hashes and turns it into a single hash. Then [`max_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) will iterate each key/value pair, returning an array containing the key value `"B"` and the sub-hash, making it easy to grab the key using `first`:

```
k = h.max_by { |k, v| v['value_2'] } # => ["B", {"value_1"=>40, "value_2"=>250}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked "What am I missing?".

I think you are missing a proper understanding of the data structures that you are using. I suggest that you try printing the data structures and take a careful look at the results.

The simplest way is `p myArray` which gives:

```
[{"A"=>{"value_1"=>30, "value_2"=>240}, "B"=>{"value_1"=>40, "value_2"=>250}, "C"=>{"value_1"=>18, "value_2"=>60}}]
```

You can get prettier results using `pp`:

```
require 'pp'
pp myArray
```

yields:

```
[{"A"=>{"value_1"=>30, "value_2"=>240},
  "B"=>{"value_1"=>40, "value_2"=>250},
  "C"=>{"value_1"=>18, "value_2"=>60}}]
```

This helps you to see that `myArray` has only one element, a Hash.

You could also look at the expression `array_hash.values.max` inside the loop:

```
myArray.each do |array_hash|
  p array_hash.values
end
```

gives:

```
[{"value_1"=>30, "value_2"=>240}, {"value_1"=>40, "value_2"=>250}, {"value_1"=>18, "value_2"=>60}]
```

Not what you expected? :-)

Given this, what would you expect to be returned by `array_hash.values.max` in the above loop?

Use `p` and/or `pp` liberally in your ruby code to help understand what's going on.